# Dependency injection at runtime using Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

`DataAccessLayer.cs` in `DataAccess` project:

```
public class DataAccessLayer : IDataAccessLayer
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

`IDataAccessLayer.cs` in `DataAccess.Contracts` project:

```
public interface IDataAccessLayer
{
    void Bar();
}
```

`MyClass.cs` in `Main` project (Console Application):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IDataAccessLayer Dal { get; set; } /// Her I want to inject dependency at runtime
}
```

I want to inject the dependency in `MyClass.Dal` property directly at runtime. I use Unity and a configuration file in main project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <container>
    <register type="DataAccess.Contracts.IDataAccessLayer, DataAccess.Contracts" mapTo="DataAccess.DataAccessLayer, DataAccess"/>
  </container>
</unity>
```

I just install Unity from Nuget in my main project.

If I do `var instance = new MyClass();` in main method of my main project, `instance.Dal` is null.

How to inject the value of Dal at runtime ?

**Update 1 :**

Ideally I would like all the dependencies of my main project to be resolved via a script in my main method or directly through the configuration. Is it possible ?

Comment: What is `Log`? You have not shown the code for that.

Comment: Oops, I have updated my answer

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx. This explains property injection with Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use constructor injection to inject dependencies in following way-

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass (IDataAccessLayer dal)
    {
        this.Dal = dal;
    }

    public IDataAccessLayer Dal { get; set; } 
}
```

To resolve the dependencies, you have to first load these into container from config.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
MyClass myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass>(); -- instance of IDataAccessLayer will be injected in myClass
```

Refer [Dependency Injection with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) to learn more about registering, resolving and injecting dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use constructor injection instead because it makes the dependencies very clear:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDataAccessLayer dal)
    {
        this.Dal = dal;
    }
    public IDataAccessLayer Dal { get; set; } 
}
```

Or use `DependencyAttribute` on your property for property injection:

```
[DependencyAttribute]
public IDataAccessLayer Dal { get; set; }
```

Please read [What does Unity Do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660864(v=pandp.20).aspx) for more details.